# How to get the root dir in Windows and Linux?

Tags: .net-core

I wrote a small software using .net6 which should run on Windows and Linux (Ubuntu). In this software I need to access a file in a folder.
Linux: /folder1/folder2/file.txt
Windows: d:\folder1\folder2\file.txt
The folder structure and the filename is the same on both systems.
This code works so far

```
string[] pfad;
pfad = new[] { "folder1", "folder2","file.txt" };
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.Combine(pfad));
```

and delivers the correct folder structur under Linux and Windows.

How can I define the root directory?
/ in Linux and d:\ in Windows
Can I detect the OS type somehow or what is the best approach?

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData); is "fix" under Windows to C:... - I want to use another drive.

Comment: As a side note: a value like d: or / should probably be in config and not in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5629588/stefan) answer but using `OperatingSystem` class instead of `RuntimeInformation` (since `OperatingSystem` is part of `System` i believe it's preferable)

```
string rootPath;

if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    rootPath = @"d:\";
else if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux())
    rootPath = "/";
else
{
    // maybe throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation** like this:

```
        string rootPath;  

        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            rootPath = @"d:\";
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            rootPath = "/";
        }
```

Comment: You can also use something like the below. (`OperatingSystem` class is part of `System` so a bit cleaner but other than that it's the same solution)

`if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows()) {...} else if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux()) {...}`

Comment: @Convel post your answer as solution so it can be marked as that ;)

Comment: @StefanMeyer done and thnx